# Android | Binary XML file error inflating class | Canot use class from local libary

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

I have a problem to use the external .aar libary in my xml-layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="42.81"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="432dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_subformular_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:background="@null"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pdf"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />


        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now, I will show my gradle.build
(build.gradle (Project))

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
```

build.gradle(App)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile(name:'android-pdf-viewer-2.7.0-beta', ext:'aar') }
```

After debugging I got the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: dtks.telekom.de.serviceapp_dev, PID: 16314
>                                                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                                       at dtks.telekom.de.serviceapp_dev.Adapters.RVAdapter_SubFormular.onCreateViewHolder(RVAdapter_SubFormular.java:43)
>                                                                                       at dtks.telekom.de.serviceapp_dev.Adapters.RVAdapter_SubFormular.onCreateViewHolder(RVAdapter_SubFormular.java:20)

Comment: please,set the cardviw width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Your CardView code is not correct. There is no `layout_width` and `layout_height` set and there is no closing angle bracket.

Use like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
```

And remove this line above the `CardView`: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: Hi Bob, i've provide only a part of the whole layout. the cardview ist correct, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the entire xml layout?  Btw, why dont you add the dependency using gradle like this: `compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta.1'`

Comment: my proxy blocks the import on this way =(. I have add the complete xml layout

Comment: In the left pane Project view of Android Studio, there will be a dropdown called 'External libraries'. Can you expand that and make sure your dependency is there? And open the library file and check the class and package names.

Comment: i have linked the libary structure @Bob

Comment: look at the top - I add the mainpart of the error-log

Comment: everything looks good. I have no idea whats wrong. Can you try the library in a sample application and make sure the library is fine?

Comment: have anyone else a idea?